# Database schema for simple stats project

Tags: database-design

**Backdrop:**

I have a file hierarchy of cvs files for multiple locations named by dates they cover ...by month specifically. Each cvs file in the folder is named after the location.

eg',
folder name: 2010-feb

contains:
location1.csv
location2.csv

Each CSV file holds records like this:

```
2010-06-28, 20:30:00 , 0
2010-06-29, 08:30:00 , 0
2010-06-29, 09:30:00 , 0
2010-06-29, 10:30:00 , 0
2010-06-29, 11:30:00 , 0
```

meaning of record columns ( column names ):

```
Date, time, # of sessions
```

I have a perl script that pulls the data from this mess and originally I was going to store it as json files, but am thinking a database might be more appropriate long term ...comparing year to year trends ...fun stuff like that.

**Pt 2 - My question/problem:**

So I now have a REST service that coughs up json with a test database. My question is [ I suck at db design ], how best to design a database backend for this?

I am thinking the following tables would suffice and keep it simple:

```
Location: (PK)location_code, name 
session: (PK)id, (FK)location_code, month, hour, num_sessions
```

I need to be able to average sessions (plus min and max) for each hour across days of week in addition to days of week in a given month or months. I've been using perl hashes to do this and am trying to decide how best to implement this with a database.

Do you think stored procedures should be used?

As to the database, depending on info gathered here, it will be postgresql or sqlite. 
If there is no compelling reason for postgresql I'll stick with sqlite.

How and where should I compare the data to hours of operation. I am storing the hours
of operation in a yaml file. I currently 'match' the hour in the data to a hash from the yaml to do this. Would a database open simpler methods? I am thinking I would do this comparison as I do now then insert the data. Can be recalled with:

```
SELECT hour, num_sessions FROM session WHERE location_code=LOC1
```

Since only hours of operation are present, I do not need to worry about it.
Should I calculate all results as I do now then store as a stats table for
different 'reports'? This, rather than processing on demand? How would this look?

Anyway ...I ramble.

Thanks for reading!

Bubnoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read of SQLite, it offers the functions you need for doing the analysis you want (sum, avg, etc), and it looks like you'll be doing that at your own api level as opposed to allowing an end user to do it themselves through an interface.  So for the simple design + small dataset you have I would look at getting all your data into SQLite.  I'd also put it in the format SQLite can understand natively, so that you can use its SQL functions without needing to convert anything first or without needing to create special functions to be used within SQL to do the conversion.

Aside from that, your design looks fine to me except for the month and hour fields.  I would leave those as full date and time fields, or possibly combine them to just one date_time field if there's an appropriate SQLite data type for that, and put the full date/time data in them (in case you'll need it later).  Then use SQLite time functions to extract the month and hour as appropriate from your full date/time fields.  As a convenience, and if SQLite supports it, you could create *calculated fields* for month and hour in the session table, which would let you immediately return the data you're looking for from a query, instead of explicitly calling time extraction functions in every query you want a month or hour for.

Also, don't forget to put indexes on fields that you set criteria on in queries.  You may not notice a difference with small data sets, but as your db gets bigger, they could make a huge difference.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding due to database ignorance/naivety. I decided to separate the hours, months due to the need to average sessions across hours regardless of month. I also need to average them within a month, also specific days --- or at least allow for the possibility. By separating time date like this I thought it would be easier than parsing out later, then processing. I will need to do more research to "get" what you describe -- "calculated fields". I'm a serious noob with regards to databases.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html . I'll have to think how I might use this as opposed to parsing it out before hand and storing separately. What about my prefab stats tables idea?

Comment: The calculated fields would allow you to split out the months and hours from the full date and time data you already have, while allowing you to keep that data if you need it later.  If you're certain you don't want/need the full date and full time, then you could certainly stick with your existing design.  My personal opinion is that it's usually more work for me to graft original data back in later than to just plan to bring it over every week/month with a script and let calculated fields split the data out for me automatically.

Comment: Calculated fields are fields where you define a formula, and the DB will run that formula whenever when a query requests that field from the table.  For instance, you could bring your full time data into its own field called time, and create a calculated field called hour that's defined as the formula strftime('%H', [time]).  Now, "SELECT hour FROM session" will automatically run that formula for you and give you just the hour for each row returned.  Same would go for making a "month" calculated field.

Comment: I wouldn't consider going with prefab stats tables until performance was unacceptably slow calculating results on the fly.  Most run-of-the-mill reporting tools do an admirable job with raw data.  Also, if you made a pre-fab stats table, you'll most likely have difficulties hooking that data into standard reporting tools, since they usually expect to do calculations off of raw data.  If you have Microsoft Access or Excel, dig into their PivotTable features, as they can do a lot of the type of analysis you're describing right off of an ODBC connection, which SQLite has a driver for I believe.

Comment: @pheadbag - Thanks,  that makes sense. I will use calculated fields as suggested. The example is much appreciated, wasn't sure how to make that work.